# How to perform sin cos operation in Microsoft Z3

Tags: z3, smt

In Microsoft Z3 Dot Net API, there is no function to perform sin cos operation. When I checked online, I found that sin and cos function values can be computed by converting the functions to Cartesian coordinates.

For example:

```
if x = cos(theta) and y = sin(theta)
x^2 + y^2 = 1
```

Using this logic, we can generate values for sin cos function.

I can generate following code:

```
(set-info :status sat)

(set-option :pp.decimal true)
(set-option :model_validate false)

(declare-fun x () Real)
(declare-fun y () Real)
(declare-fun theta () Real)

(assert (= (cos theta) x))
(assert (= (sin theta) y))
(assert (= (+ (* x x) (* y y)) 1))
(check-sat-using qfnra-nlsat)
(get-model)
(reset)
```

The output I am getting now is like this:

```
sat
(model 
  (define-fun x () Real
    0.125)
  (define-fun y () Real
    (- 0.9921567416?))
  (define-fun theta () Real
    (+ (acos (- 0.125)) pi))
)
```

What is not clear to me is, how can I get the sin(theta) or cos(theta) value for a given theta in Z3? Can anyone please help me to make the smt code?

What is the "(+ (acos (- 0.125)) pi))" value I am getting in the result?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is going to work in all possible cases (nlsat is a bit special), but you can use `get-value` to get arbitrary expressions evaluated under the model, e.g., after `(check-sat-using ...)` you can add

```
(get-value (theta))
(get-value ((sin theta)))
```

to get

```
((theta (+ (acos (- 0.125)) pi)))
(((sin theta) (- 0.9921567416?)))
```

Note that `?` indicates that the value has been truncated; there are options to adjust the precision. For instance, without `pp.decimal=true`, the precise result is reported as

```
(((sin theta) (root-obj (+ (* 64 (^ x 2)) (- 63)) 1)))
```

(an algebraic number).